# MATLAB - efficient way of computing distances between points in a graph/network using the adjacency matrix and coordinates

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, euclidean-distance

I have the network representation in a 2D coordinate space. I have an adjacency matrix `Adj`(which is sparse) and a `coordinate` matrix with the x,y values of all the points/nodes/vertices in the graph which are drawn.

I would like to compute as efficiently as possible the distance between these points. I would like to avoid cycling through the entries in the matrix and computing the pairwise distances one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[n, d] = size(coordinate);
assert(d == 2);
resi = sparse(Adj * diag(1:n));
resj = sparse(diag(1:n) * Adj);
res = sparse(zeros(n));
f = find(Adj)
res(f) = sqrt((coordinate(resi(f), 1) - coordinate(resj(f), 1)) .^ 2 + (coordinate(resi(f), 2) - coordinate(resj(f), 2)) .^ 2);
```

EDIT: Oops, fixed a bug

Clarification: I'm assuming by coordinate matrix you mean like http://www.passagesoftware.net/webhelp/Coordinate_Matrix.htm

EDIT 2: I'm actually not sure whether Adj is a matrix of logicals (or whether you can have a sparse matrix of logicals).  I fixed it to sidestep that potential pitfall

Comment: My matrices have increased in size and `Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options. Error in ==> modularize_graphs_Alex_hugeMats at 50 res(i,j) = sqrt((coordinate(resi(i,j), 1) - coordinate(resj(i,j), 1)) .^ 2 +...` is there any way to save space? I have also changed `f=find(Adj)` to `[i,j]=find(Adj)`.

Comment: My matrices have increased in size and `??? Error using ==> find
Matrix is too large to return linear indices. Use [i,j] = find(S) for sparse matrix. Error in ==> modularize_graphs_Alex_hugeMats at 49 [f] = find(graph_temp);` and then I made the change and `Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options. Error in ==> modularize_graphs_Alex_hugeMats at 50 res(f) = sqrt((coordinate(resi(f), 1) - coordinate(resj(f), 1)) .^ 2 +...` is there any way to save space?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you if you're running out of memory.  I know Octave has something called oct-files for storing really large sparse matrices, but I've never used them and I don't know what Matlab has.

Answer (score 1):

If your graph is sparse, then you should consider using [adjacency lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) instead.

Iterating through the adjacency lists will allow you to get all pairs of connected points in time linear in the number of pairs, as opposed iterating through empty entries in the adjacency matrix.

Comment: The problem can be done with no iteration at all as I showed in my solution

Comment: Of course it's iterating, it's just doing it at the native level instead of the MATLAB interpreted level. You get things to run faster with native code but the asymptotic efficiency is still bad.

Comment: That's what I meant, and even at the native level my solution is only iterating over the pairs in the adjacency matrix

Comment: You're still iterating over the entire matrix with `find`.

Comment: No, because Adj is a sparse matrix.  That means internally it's stored as a list of all the nonzero elements. I believe find is optimized for sparse matrices to just return that list.