# MATLAB, how to compute the distances between large coordinate sets, without exceeding memory constraints?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, coordinates, sparse-matrix

(using `MATLAB`) I have a large coordinate matrix and a large sparse adjacency matrix for which coordinates are connected to each other. I had asked previously on SO, how to *efficiently* compute these distances in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15482539/410975), but I have run into **memory problems** now which are a much more severe issue.

I used this MATLAB function to compute the distance matrix `Dists = pdist2(fruchterman_graph(:,:),fruchterman_graph(:,:),'euclidean');` but it fails on large networks for both speed and finally memory.

This is the code which runs only on smallish graphs (not hundreds of thousands):

```
coordinate = kamada_graph;
    [n, d] = size(kamada_graph);
    assert(d == 2);
    resi = sparse(adj*  spdiags((1:n)',0,n,n));
    resj = sparse(spdiags((1:n)',0,n,n) * adj);
    res = sparse(n,n);
    f = find(adj);  
    res(f) = sqrt((coordinate(resi(f), 1) - coordinate(resj(f), 1)) .^ 2 +...
                          (coordinate(resi(f), 2) - coordinate(resj(f), 2)) .^ 2);
```

This on *large* graphs creates

> ??? Error using ==> find Matrix is too large to return linear indices.
>   Use `[i,j] = find(S)` for sparse matrix.
>   Error in ==> modularize_graphs at 49 `[f] = find(adj)`;

I changed the line which is referred to to be:

```
[i,j] = find(ajd);    
res(i,j) = sqrt((coordinate(resi(i,j), 1) - coordinate(resj(i,j), 1)) .^ 2 +...
    (coordinate(resi(i,j), 2) - coordinate(resj(i,j), 2)) .^ 2);
```

and on the smallish network now (~500 vertices) the error:

> ??? Out of memory.
>   Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
>   Error in ==> modularize_graphs at 50
>       `res(i,j) = sqrt((coordinate(resi(i,j), 1) - coordinate(resj(i,j), 1)) .^ 2 +...`

Is there anyway to compute the distance matrix using the adjacency matrix and a coordinate matrix, `(N,2)` of `x`,`y` values, without falling into memory issues and possibly making it not too slow as well?

The desired output is a matrix of distances, the distances between all points that are connected according to the `Adj` adjacency matrix.

Comment: At this point, you most likely have to sacrifice speed to lower the memory requirements. Or buy more RAM.

Comment: @Jonas, hmm, there must be a way to at least sacrifice speed. I need it to at least work. It is not something complicated I need to get going. Is there a *turtle* approach at least which will not crash?

Comment: I'm not certain, but it might help to replace `f` with `[x y]`.

Comment: @RoneyMichael, I did and it creates a bigger memory issue. I show in the question `[i,j] = find(graph_temp);
res(i,j) = sqrt((coordinate(resi(i,j), 1) - coordinate(resj(i,j), 1)) .^ 2 +... (coordinate(resi(i,j), 2) - coordinate(resj(i,j), 2)) .^ 2);` there must be a clever way

Comment: Definitely a worthwhile qns. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate pointwise distances with using a minimum amount of memory, you can always iterate through your adjacency matrix on an element-wise basis:

```
%# assuming a square and symmetric adjacency matrix
nCoords = size(adjMat,1);

%# there are at most (n^2-n) distances 
%# if this runs out of memory already, there 
%# is a way to only store existing distances to save 
%# even more memory
distances = NaN((nCoords^2-nCoords)/2,1);

ct = 0;
for row = 1:nCoords
   for col = 1:row-1
     ct = ct+1;
     if adjacencyMatrix(row,col)
        distances(ct) = sum( (coordinate(row,:)-coordinate(col,:)).^2 );
     end
   end
end

distances = sqrt(distances);
```

---

With the sparse approach, you may want to try the following (I don't think you need `resi` and `resj`, unless I totally misunderstand your problem).

```
[row,col]=find(adjacencyMatrix);

distances = sqrt(sum( (coordinate(row,:) - coordinate(col,:)).^2 ,2));

sparseDistanceMatrix = sparse(row,col,distances);
```

Comment: is there not a way to do it using `bsxfun` or `adjacency lists` in some way? My sparse matrices have half a million vertices.

Comment: @Vass: I showed you the minimum memory approach. However, on closer inspection, your workaround might be improved. See my edit.

Comment: thanks for the answer and edit, but this is not producing a distance matrix. It produces a vector and the order does not seem to be related to the order of the other approaches or pdist2.

Comment: @Vass: Oh, I see. The order is the same as the order of the adjacency matrix. What kind of distance matrix output do you need?

Comment: `Dists=pdist2(coordinates(:,:),coordinates(:,:),'euclidean');` does it, using the coordinate matrices (N,2) for x,y, it generates a matrix of the distance between every point. It later gets masked by doing `(Dists) .* adj` for which distances are connected to each other so there is in a way a *weighted adjacency matrix* according to euclidean distance

Comment: `pdists` calculates the distances for points that are not even connected together via the adjacency matrix and the other approach saves time by calculating for only the edges connected together

Comment: @Vass: I have added a way for you to create the sparse distance matrix, that has distances wherever `adjacencyMatrix == 1`

Comment: `[row,col]=find(adjacencyMatrix); distances = sqrt(sum( (coordinate(row,:) - coordinate(col,:)).^2 ,2)); sparseDistanceMatrix = sparse(row,col,distances);` works great, thanks, and it's simple.