# Compute distance between combinations of points in a grid

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, distance, a-star

I am looking for an efficient solution to the following problem. This should work with `python`, but does not have to be *in* `python`.

I have a 2D matrix, each element of the matrix represents a point in a 2D, orthogonal grid. I want to compute the **shortest distance between couples of points in the grid**. This would be trivial if there were no "obstacles" in the grid.

A figure helps explaining:[image: Grid with paths]

Each cell in the figure is one element of the matrix (the matrix is square, but it could be rectangular). **Gray cells** are obstacles, any path between two points must go around them. The **green cells** are those I am interested in. I am not interested in **red cells**, but a path can go trough them.

The distance between points like A and B is trivial to compute, but how to compute the path between A and C as shown in the figure?

I have read about the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), but since I am working with a rather big grid, generally (few hundred) x (few hundred), I was wondering if there is a smarter alternative. Remember: I have to find the distance between all couples of "green cells", not just between two of them. If I have n green cells, I will have a number of combinations equal to the binomial coefficient (n 2).

The grid is fixed, I have to compute all the distances once and them use them in further calculations, say accessing them based on the relevant indices in the matrix.

Note: the problem is NOT [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482539/matlab-efficient-way-of-computing-distances-between-points-in-a-graph-network), were coordinates are in a list. My 2D coordinates are organised in a 2D grid and the question is about exploiting this aspect for having a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: What is the difference between gray and red?

Comment: If you need to compute *all* shortest distances, then you have (roughly) the square of the number of green cells distances to store; how does the grid being fixed help with this?

Comment: Gray and red: as stated, gray are obstacles, a path cannot go through them. Red are simply "uninteresting" points, actually missing data, no need to get the distance from them. Probably inessential, but I thought I would mention it.

Comment: Concerning "all shortest distances": no, it's not the square of the number of green cells (n), it's a binomial coefficient (n 2), the (non-ordered) combinations of two cells among all the green ones. Not directly related to the fact that the grid is fixed.

Comment: You can try likely cases of your data in [this visualisation of search algorithms](https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/) and decide, which one is likely to get the fastest results.

Comment: @Piinthesky Interesting, but I think the problem is slightly different, since the distance I search is not restricted to paths following 0/45/90 degrees directions (see AC in my figure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the most straightforward solution would be the [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm, which computes the shortest distances between all pairs of nodes in a graph. This doesn't necessarily exploit the fact that you happen to have a 2D grid (it could work on other kinds of graphs too), but it should work fine. The fact that you do have a 2D grid may enable you to implement it more efficiently than if you had to write an implementation for any arbitrary graph (e.g. you can just store distances as they're computed in a matrix, instead of some less efficient data structure).

The regular version only produces the distances of all shortest paths as output, and doesn't actually store the paths themselves as output. There's additional info on the wikipedia page on how to modify the algorithm to enable you to efficiently reconstruct paths if necessary.

Intuitively, I suspect more efficient implementations may be possible which do exploit the fact that you have a 2D grid, probably using ideas from [Rectangular Symmetry Reduction](https://harablog.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/rectangular-symmetry-reduction/) and/or [Jump Point Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_point_search). Both of those ideas are traditionally used with A* for single-pair pathfinding queries though, I'm not aware of any work using them for all-pair shortest path computations. My intuition says they can be exploited there too, but in the time it'll take to figure that out exactly and implement it correctly, you can probably much more easily implement and run Floyd-Warshall.

Comment: And, incidentally, I do not need the path, just the distance, so even more to the point.

Comment: And, for reference, it even has a python (scipy) implementation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.floyd_warshall.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.floyd_warshall